# How do I add a Mesh to an AActor at runtime in c++ in Unreal Engine 5.3

Tags: c++, unreal-5, spawning

For Unreal 5.0, 5.1 and 5.2 I used the following code to do this:

```
TCHAR* name = "someasset";

UStaticMesh * o = Cast<UStaticMesh>(StaticLoadObject(UStaticMesh::StaticClass(), NULL, name, name));
actor = munrealcontext->uworld->SpawnActor<AActor>();
meshcomponent = NewObject<UStaticMeshComponent>(actor);
meshcomponent->RegisterComponent();
actor->SetRootComponent(meshcomponent);
meshcomponent->SetStaticMesh(mesh);
```

Since UE 5.3, it crashes at meshcomponent->SetStaticMesh(mesh);

What has changed? What's wrong?

The Exception thrown is "Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000005."

callstack:

```
    UnrealEditor-Core.dll!00007ffc9ec8fccf()    Unknown
    UnrealEditor-CoreUObject.dll!00007ffca8e2442d() Unknown
    UnrealEditor-CoreUObject.dll!00007ffca8da1c8d() Unknown
    UnrealEditor-Core.dll!00007ffc9efc5180()    Unknown
    UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!00007ffbbc925321()  Unknown
>   GameLib.dll!MUnrealSpawn::Init(UStaticMesh * mesh) Line 56  C++
    GameLib.dll!MUnrealMesh::Init(UStaticMesh * mesh) Line 15   C++
    GameLib.dll!StaticLevel::VisInit() Line 69  C++
    GameLib.dll!SyncState::Init() Line 620  C++
    GameLib.dll!Application::OnlineProcess() Line 1213  C++
    GameLib.dll!Application::Process() Line 697 C++
    GameLib.dll!MApplicationRunner::Process() Line 221  C++
    GameLib.dll!GameLibRender() Line 162    C++
    UnrealEditor-Game-Win64-DebugGame.dll!AGameActor::Tick(float DeltaTime) Line 207    C++
```